# batch - echo in multiple colors

Tags: batch-file, colors

I'm new to using batch but I know basic commands. I'm trying to show one message (via echo or something like that) in one color. And another message in another color. (the color command colors all the text in the window instead of letting me choose what to color)
I want to do this without external software (although I am using DOSBox instead of cmd - if it matters at all), please explain your code so I can understand and learn.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4453

Here's a ready for use color function

Comment: I type: "myprogram 5 onetwothree" and it ouputs "Final Version 20" in different colors, how do I input that with text and color?